# C: Using time() function to estimate seconds elapsed since specific date

Tags: c, time

I am having a bit of trouble here. I am tasked with finding how many seconds have elapsed since January 1, 1970 using the time function. It must include now = time (NULL)

My issue is I was never given a solid explanation as to how the time function works, so I have no idea how to get it to tell answer the problem I am being asked.

Comment: so did you google for what "time" function in C is?

Comment: Well you will get solid info if you do man time at Linux system and simple search in internet is enough.

Answer (score 1):

A call to `time(NULL)` returns the number of seconds elapsed since the UNIX epoch, or January 1, 1970 UTC. This is the singular purpose of this function.

If you want to know how it works, look up the [documentation on it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time).

Comment: Ok awesome, thanks a lot. My professor didn't really go over it. You rock!

Comment: If you're using a UNIX type system never underestimate how useful the `man` command can be, or barring that, a [good reference site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Nobody's expected to intuitively know how anything works, that's why there's detailed documentation on these things. Have your reference material on hand at all times when writing code.